# Cannot merge my list into a specific part of my code (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot figure out how to create a tupil/list making it so when I pick the pizzas I like it prints out, "you have picked pizzas, x, x,x ,x " I have tried many times by using the tupil or list  + for loop.

I had used this,

```
selected_premium_pizzas = []; # list
selected_premium_pizzas.append( x ); # x being the pizza's numeric value
```

I just simply cannot figure out how to make it loop through your data and specify the pizza type according to the pizza value.

```
for int i in range(0,len(selected_premium_pizzas)):
print( 'Premium Pizza, "' + premium_pizzas[selected_premium_pizzas[i]-1] + '", selected.' );
```

into this code here,

```
num_pizzas = -1
    while( num_pizzas <= 0 ) or ( num_pizzas > 5 ):
        try:
            num_pizzas = int( input( 'How many pizzas would you like (max of 5):'))
            if num_pizzas =="":
                print("Error cannot be more than 5")
        except:
            print('Invalid Input')

    pizza_dict = {"premium_pizza_price":8.50, "gourmet_pizza_price":13.50, "selected_pizzas":0, "num_premium_pizzas":0, "num_gourmet_pizzas":0}
    print('\n==Premium Pizzas==\n')
    for i in range (0,len(premium_pizzas)):
        print (str(i+1) + '. ' + premium_pizzas[i])
    print('\n==Gourmet Pizzas==\n')
    for i in range (0,len(gourmet_pizzas)):
        print (str(i+1) + '. ' + gourmet_pizzas[i])

    print('\nEnter "next" to move on.\n')

    while(True):
        if( num_pizzas == 0 ):
            break;
        try:
            selected = input('Select Your Premium Pizza: ')
            if(selected == 'next'):
                break;
            else:
                selected = int(selected)
            if(selected<=0) or (selected > len(premium_pizzas)):
                print("Invalid Input")
            else:
                pizza_dict['num_premium_pizzas'] +=1
                num_pizzas -=1
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")

        print(' ')

    while(True):
        if( num_pizzas == 0 ):
            break;
        try:
            selected = input("Select Your Gourmet Pizza: ")
            if(selected == "next"):
                break;
            else:
                selected = int(selected)
            if(selected<=0) or (selected > len(gourmet_pizzas)):
                print('Invalid Input')
            else:
                pizza_dict['num_gourmet_pizzas']+=1
                num_pizzas -=1
        except:
            print('Invalid Input')
```

Comment: your code is faulty in several places : `for int i in range(0,len(selected_premium_pizzas)):` should be `for i in range(len(selected_premium_pizzas)):` . Also , `premium_pizzas[selected_premium_pizzas[i]-1]` should be `premium_pizzas[selected_premium_pizzas[i]]`

Comment: It's not that you've been asking "too much", but too badly - your questions are not up to the standard expected here. Please read the content in the Help Center, starting with [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "pyhton", "tupil", ... if you write your code like you write your questions then you're bound to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing the exact error you are getting, but the problem is most likely in the

```
premium_pizzas[selected_premium_pizzas[i]-1]
```

part. the premium_pizzas variable is not declared in the part of the code you are listing, so i can't be sure what the mistake is.

However, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, so I list the most probable options. If you want to select pizzas in a specific value range

```
selected = [pizza for pizza in pizzas_dict if pizzas_dict[pizza] >= price_min and pizzas_dict[pizza] <= price_max]
```

In a similar manner, if you want to select pizza by some part of its name ('description')

```
selected = [pizza for pizza in pizzas_dict if description in pizza]
```

If you want the user the select pizzas 1,3,4 and return the values, then a dictionary is not the correct structure, since it is not ordered, and you should use a list instead. However, there is really no point in doing a such thing. A user should select by some specific criterion, not by an arbitrary index number.